# Dynamically create new role for Jetstream Teams

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I know this is a vauge question. I also know that roles and permission of Laravel Jetstream Teams are under JetstreamProvider where you can hardcoded new or edit a role.

I just can't help myself how to do it dynamically via a web portal.

Do you have any ideas and recommendation for this matter? I have search and even look on jetstream github but no avail. I appreciate all you suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: You might get more answers if you can explain what you mean by "web portal". Is "web portal" something that already exists or are you asking people to give you the code to enable CRUD features for managing teams?

Comment: Did you find any ideas how to implement it and binding to jetstream service provider?

Comment: The `configurePermissions` function in `JetstreaServiceProvider` is where you can do this (as you mentioned). Do note it is just a function and you can call models from it. So if I was you I would create separate model, view and controller to add the custom roles and their permissions to db. Once in DB all you need to do is read the same and declare them in this function. Thus making it dynamic. You will need to implement the full UI and the backend logic for these custom permissions yourself though.